# How to get a value from an XML using XPath in Go

Tags: xml, xpath, go

Looking at [go xml package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml) I could not find such possibility.
[Go](http://golang.org) only allows to define tree of structures, map them to XML tree and deserialize using `xml.NewDecoder(myXmlString).Decode(myStruct)`.

Even if I define needed tree of Go structures, I still can't query that tree using XPath.

C# has convenient function [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335970%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that allows to select value from XML tree by specifying XPath without duplicating whole tree structure in C# classes.

Is there similar possibility in Go ?
If not then what is simplest way to implement it (possibly reusing xml package) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though not xpath, you can read values out of XML with the native [go xml encoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) package. You would use the xml.Unmarshal() function. [Here](http://play.golang.org/p/O4_y4AMYJR) is a go play example.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/xml"

func main() {
    type People struct {
        Names []string `xml:"Person>FullName"`
    }

    data := `
        <People>
            <Person>
                <FullName>Jerome Anthony</FullName>
            </Person>
            <Person>
                <FullName>Christina</FullName>
            </Person>
        </People>
    `

    v := People{Names: []string{}}
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Names of people: %q", v)
}
```

Comment: While this is certainly a good answer in general, I've downvoted it because the OP actually specified using _XPath_ syntax to retrieve values from a XML object. This solution sidesteps the issue and does not use XPath syntax at all!

Answer (score 15):

There's also the [xmlpath](http://godoc.org/launchpad.net/xmlpath) package.

Sample usage:

```
path := xmlpath.MustCompile("/library/book/isbn")
root, err := xmlpath.Parse(file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if value, ok := path.String(root); ok {
    fmt.Println("Found:", value)
}
```

Comment: Do you know how it could be used with http.Get output?

Comment: New link: https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2

Answer (score 14):

There is no xpath parsing in the standard packages of Go, so you need to resort to using a 3rd party package.

Then one I know of is [Gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri)
The package is based on *libxml2* using *cgo*

The subpackage you want to import is `github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xpath`

Answer (score 6):

[xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) lets you extract data from XML documents using XPath expression.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "github.com/antchfx/xmlquery"
)

func main() {
    htmlstr := `<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>this is a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>Hello,World</body>
    </html>`
    root, err := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(htmlstr))
    if err != nil {
         panic(err)
     }
    title := xmlquery.FindOne(root, "//title")
    fmt.Println(title.InnerText())
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, @antchfx's solution, unlike `xmlpath` mentioned by @rzymek, does _not_ require pre-compilation of XPath expressions. Instead, XML queries are _cached_ and reused if needed. It's an alternative approach. I wonder if anyone benchmarked `xmlquery` vs. `xmlpath`. I would guess that pre-compiled XPath expressions, which _can_ be used for _different_ XML objects, might be more efficient. But if you're dealing with just _one_ XML object, `xmlquery` might have an edge. It's interesting to see each approach, side-by-side; `xmlpath` seems more idiomatic, but `xmlquery` is more intuitive.